# KQL Query to filter Message based on Grafana Variable

Tags: azure, azure-functions, grafana, kql

In an KQL Query, displaying Azure Function App Logs, that will be used in Grafana, we want to have an Variable "Show Host Status Messages" in Grafana.

If "$ShowHostStatus" == True, show all Messages.
If "$ShowHostStatus" == False, show all Messages, but filter out all messages starting with "Host Status".   (where Message !startswith "Host Status")

Would it be possible to use a Query similar to this, applying some inline filter for messages inside {Message_Filtered_For_Host_Status} ?

```
FunctionAppLogs
| where AppName == "$FunctionApp"
| extend Message = iff(("$ShowHostStatus" == "True"), Message, {Message_Filtered_For_Host_Status} )
| project TimeGenerated, FunctionName, Level, Message
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a Granfa to test sorry, but would something like the following work?

```
| where "$ShowHostStatus" or Message !startswith 'Host Status'
```

PoC code with different variable name.

```
let FunctionAppLogs = datatable (TimeGenerated:datetime, FunctionName:string, Level:int, Message:string, AppName:string) [
datetime('2024-03-27'), 'Blah', 1, 'Host Status 1', '$FunctionApp',
datetime('2024-03-27'), 'Blah', 2, 'Status 1', '$FunctionApp',
datetime('2024-03-27'), 'Blah', 3, 'Host Status 2', '$FunctionApp',
datetime('2024-03-27'), 'Blah', 1, 'Something 1', '$FunctionApp'
];
let ShowHostStatus = false;
FunctionAppLogs
| where AppName == "$FunctionApp"
| where ShowHostStatus or Message !startswith 'Host Status'
| project TimeGenerated, FunctionName, Level, Message
```

| TimeGenerated | FunctionName | Level | Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-27T00:00:00Z | Blah | 2 | Status 1 |
| 2024-03-27T00:00:00Z | Blah | 1 | Something 1 |